# Blazor WebAssembly (.NET Core Hosted - Not PWA) Force Clear Cache or Force Update

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Good day everyone

I have created a Blazor WebAssembly with .NET Core Hosted, and we did not use PWA, the application is working great then we have made an update on the system, after we deploy it, some of the testers is still getting the old version of the application, while others is getting the new one, we advise them to clear the cache on their browser and phone which is working, but the clients are not that knowledgeable when it comes to clearing cache on their browser, especially for those who are accessing the system on their mobile phones. So, we have to force update the dll's on the user's browser, I tried the cache-control on the header, but no effect, I tried to put a versioning on the javascript and stylesheets, but no effect.

I saw some of the fix, but it is for PWA, but we don't use PWA on our apps, is there a way to force the new update on the user's browser, without telling them to clear the cache on their devices?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'm researching this question before we make a possible change to web assembly and want to know if you asked this question in the .NET Github repository?